# Correct design pattern to change instance of data type at run time

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I had been thinking of using a [generic factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628251/java-factory-pattern-with-generics) for this, however I just want to make sure that I am using it correctly.

First of all, this has to be Java-based, due to client needs.

My application can instantiate several objects, and each of those objects should be able to change type at run time.  For instance, a variable can start out as a float, be converted to an int, then to a char, then back to a float.  That would be a basic example, however custom data types can be added in for extra fun.

Is a generic factory pattern the correct one to use in this case?  Or, is there something better?  To me, the factory pattern seems to be better at instantiating and not updating (unless if I essentially destroyed and re-instantiated the variable).

---

More detail:

This is an evolutionary algorithm where I don't necessarily know the types when the program starts.  It may find that an int is more desirable than a float, based on how evolution goes.

For instance, if I start with a floating point value of 4.34:

```
// start of program
object var = 4.34;

// evolution running......
...

// evolution determines that var would be better as a float
var.convertToInt();

// var is now an int with a value of 4
```

My initial thought had been to have a generic factory type object where I keep track of the current 'type' of the object and return the appropriate value.  So in the beginning it would return a `float`, and after the conversion would return the int-converted value (mapped to an internal `int`).

---

Edit 2: Code clarification.

I guess my point is just not coming through.  Here is an example of what I would expect to see, code-wise.

```
object var = new object(int, 4);    // create int variable with value of 4
// where object is whatever base design pattern i am using here
...
var.toFloat();                      // convert var to float, value is now 4.0
System.out.println(var.getValue()); // prints 4.0
...
var.toCustomClass();                // var is now a custom datatype
System.out.println(var.getValue()); // calls the print method of the class
```

I should also mention that the instance of `var` needs to persist throughout execution, as it is an object within my evolutionary algorithm and can't be destroyed and re-instantiated as something else.

Comment: A variable of type `float` cannot become an `int`. Do you mean `Number`? Programming to interfaces? Inversion of control? Dependency Injection?

Comment: Yes, directly it cannot.  However, for my application I need to convert the base type and figure out a way to represent that.

Comment: I still don't understand what you expect or what you are trying to do. Make all your references of type `Object`.

Comment: More clarification added...hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you explain why you want to do this it might help. Your best bet based on what you have said so far will be just to always use the type as Number and then store whatever version you need. For example `number.toInt`, `number.toDouble` etc.

For more complex types define a common interface that they all implement and store them using that interface, then write appropriate mapping methods or use a library such as Dozer to do the mapping for you.

You are going to need to create your own class to handle this. For example:

```
public class Value {
     Object value;

     Object getValue();


     void toInteger() {
        if (value instanceof Number) {
           value = Integer.valueOf(((Number)value).intValue());
        } else {
           // Handle the conversion however you handle it
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The edit was meant to reflect what I really want.  Essentially I will define the types at the start of the program, but those can change over the execution of the program.  I would like to have an extensible pattern I can use to handle this type change, as it is not always going to be as easy as typecasting to an int.  It could be a complex data structure that is transformed to some other comparable data structure.

Comment: It really sounds like you are over-complicating this. Is there any reason you can't just always use `double` for numerical data for example? Or `BigDecimal` if accuracy is more important than speed...

Comment: It is possible that the data type can change from a double to int to bool to custom class all within the same execution (the fun of the evolutionary algorithm is that what happens is anybody's guess).  I definitely don't want to overcomplicate it if I don't have to however.

Comment: @espais See edit. I'd still be checking your architecture first though, you seem convinced you need to do this but I really really doubt that you do.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The reason I'm convinced I need something like this is that it will not always be the case that the data will be numeric.  As I mentioned, I basically have an object getting passed around an evolutionary algorithm that needs a flexible type (I am extending a pre-existing framework, so I don't really want to muck around too much in how it handles objects).  The numerics were more for an example...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

By providing a generic method, the return type is casted to the type of the variable to hold the result. A ClassCastException will be launched if the types are not compatible

```
public class Wrapper {

private Object src;

public Wrapper(Object o) {
    src = o;
}
public String getType(){
    return src.getClass().getName();
}

public <E> E getValue() {
    return (E)src;
}
public void toInteger(){
    //dummy implementation
    if(src instanceof Double){
        src=new Integer(String.valueOf((int)Math.floor((Double)src)));
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Wrapper wrapper=new Wrapper(new Double(4.8));
    System.out.println(wrapper.getType());
    Double myDouble=wrapper.getValue();
    System.out.println(myDouble);
    wrapper.toInteger();
    System.out.println(wrapper.getType());
    Integer myInteger=wrapper.getValue();
 // Double exceptionInProgress = wrapper.getValue();
    System.out.println(myInteger);
}
```

}