# Factory pattern and Generics

Tags: java, generics, factory

I sometimes run into this scenario and not sure if I'm using a bad approach or I just don't know how to solve it.

Let's say I have two classes and two beans like this:

```
public class BeanOne {
    public void methodBeanOne() {
        //...
    }
}

public class BeanTwo {
    public void methodBeanTwo() {
        //...
    }
}

public class ClassOne {
    private BeanOne bean;

    public ClassOne(BeanOne bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    public void methodclassOne() {
        bean.methodBeanOne();
    }
}

public class ClassTwo {
    private BeanTwo bean;

    public ClassTwo(BeanTwo bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    public void methodClassTwo() {
        bean.methodBeanTwo();
    }
}
```

I want to make a generic abstract class , so I can extract some logic from `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` to it, and an abstract bean with common methods as well:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean {
    public void commonMethod() {
        //...
    }
}

public class BeanOne extends AbstractBean {
    public void methodBeanOne() {
        //...
    }
}

public class BeanTwo extends AbstractBean {
    public void methodBeanTwo() {
        //...
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends AbstractBean> {
    protected T bean;

    public AbstractClass(T bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }

    public void commonClassMethod(){
        bean.commonMethod();
    }
}

public class ClassOne extends AbstractClass<BeanOne> {

    public ClassOne(BeanOne bean) {
        super(bean);
    }

    public void methodclassOne() {
        bean.methodBeanOne();
    }
}

public class ClassTwo extends AbstractClass<BeanTwo> {

    public ClassTwo(BeanTwo bean) {
        super(bean);
    }

    public void methodClassTwo() {
        bean.methodBeanTwo();
    }
}
```

So far, so good.

The next step would be to create a factory to get one implementation based on an `enum` for instance, and here is where I start getting errors:

```
public class ClassFactory {

    public enum MyEnum {
        ONE, TWO;
    }

    private ClassFactory() {
    }

    public static AbstractClass newInstance(MyEnum value, AbstractBean bean) {
        switch(value){
        case ONE:
            return new ClassOne(bean);
        case TWO:
            return new ClassTwo(bean);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following compilation errors:

```
The constructor ClassOne(AbstractBean) is undefined
The constructor ClassTwo(AbstractBean) is undefined
```

I've also tried:

```
public class ClassFactory {

    public enum MyEnum {
        ONE, TWO;
    }

    private ClassFactory() {
    }

    public static <T extends AbstractBean> AbstractClass<T> newInstance(MyEnum value, T bean) {
        switch(value){
        case ONE:
            return new ClassOne(bean);
        case TWO:
            return new ClassTwo(bean);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ClassOne to AbstractClass<T>
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ClassTwo to AbstractClass<T>
```

And I'm pretty much stuck there. I think I understand this error, but then, is it possible to create such a factory class **trying to avoid castings**?

I've also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628251/java-factory-pattern-with-generics), but can't fully understand how it'd help me.

**EDIT: Visitor Pattern**

Ok, so I've tried the Visitor Pattern described in the previos post:

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    T visit(BeanOne bean);

    T visit(BeanTwo bean);
}

public abstract class AbstractBean {
    public void commonMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    public abstract <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
}

public class BeanOne extends AbstractBean {
    public void methodBeanOne() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class BeanTwo extends AbstractBean {
    public void methodBeanTwo() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class ClassFactory {
    private ClassFactory() {
    }

    public static AbstractClass<? extends AbstractBean> newInstance(AbstractBean bean) {
        return bean.accept(new AbstractClassVisitor());
    }
}

public class AbstractClassVisitor implements Visitor<AbstractClass<? extends AbstractBean>> {

    @Override
    public AbstractClass<? extends AbstractBean> visit(BeanOne bean) {
        return ClassFactory.newInstance(bean);
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractClass<? extends AbstractBean> visit(BeanTwo bean) {
        return ClassFactory.newInstance(bean);
    }
}
```

But using it like this:

```
AbstractBean bean = new BeanOne();
AbstractClass<? extends AbstractBean> clazz = ClassFactory.newInstance(bean);
clazz.commonClassMethod();
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.<init>(AbstractClassVisitor.java:3)
    at test.ClassFactory.newInstance(ClassFactory.java:9)
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.visit(AbstractClassVisitor.java:7)
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.visit(AbstractClassVisitor.java:1)
    at test.BeanOne.accept(BeanOne.java:10)
    at test.ClassFactory.newInstance(ClassFactory.java:9)
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.visit(AbstractClassVisitor.java:7)
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.visit(AbstractClassVisitor.java:1)
    at test.BeanOne.accept(BeanOne.java:10)
    at test.ClassFactory.newInstance(ClassFactory.java:9)
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.visit(AbstractClassVisitor.java:7)
    at test.AbstractClassVisitor.visit(AbstractClassVisitor.java:1)
    at test.BeanOne.accept(BeanOne.java:10)
    ...
```

I can see why this is happening, am I missing something?

Comment: When you're calling `super(bean);` inside `ClassOne` - constructor of which class are you calling ?

Comment: @alfasin I'd be calling `public AbstractClass(T bean)` constructor in class `AbstractClass`.

Comment: In the first code example there is no `AbstractClass` and `ClassOne` does not extend any class.

Comment: @alfasin True, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question you supplied yourself, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630501/144302

The same principle applies to your problem: use either a factory with overloaded methods

```
public class ClassFactory {

  private ClassFactory() {
  }

  public static AbstractClass<BeanOne> newInstance(BeanOne bean) {
    return new ClassOne(bean);
  }

  public static AbstractClass<BeanTwo> newInstance(BeanTwo bean) {
    return new ClassTwo(bean);
  }
}
```

or, as pointed out in the answer, apply a principle like double dispatch where you add a method `AbstractClass<T> newInstance()` to `AbstractBean` and implement it appropriately in each specialization. E.g.

```
class BeanOne { /* ... */ 
   public AbstractBean<BeanOne> newInstance() {
      return ClassFactory.newInstance(this);
   }
}
```

You can finally add the following method to `ClassFactory`

```
public static <T> AbstractClass<T> newInstance(AbstractBean<T> bean) {
   return bean.newInstance();
}
```

For specific advantages and disadvantages, I would encourage you to read the whole answer in the other question (it's very good and I don't want to copy other's work blindly).

Comment: I've edited my answer adding the Visitor Pattern approach described on the other thread, but now I'm getting a `StackOverflowError`. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `AbstractClassVisitor` do?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that class.

Comment: In the abstract visitor class you have to return the concrete instances of `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` instead of referring back to the factory method or you'll add specific methods to the factory class receiving `BeanOne` and `BeanTwo` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the constructor argument `public ClassOne(BeanOne bean)`. You tried to supplies `AbstractBean` which is parent of `BeanOne` as the constructor argument. Java only allows object widening not narrowing. Try to type cast the parent object into specific child as follows:

```
public static AbstractClass newInstance(MyEnum value, AbstractBean bean) {
    switch(value):
    case ONE:
        return new ClassOne((BeanOne)bean);
    case TWO:
        return new ClassTwo((BeanTwo)bean);
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

But make sure when you invoke the `newInstance` method, provides the correct object instance.
Otherwise ClassCastException might occur.

Edit:

```
public static AbstractClass newInstance(MyEnum value) {
    switch(value):
    case ONE:
        return new ClassOne(new BeanOne());
    case TWO:
        return new ClassTwo(new BeanTwo());
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wanted to know if there's a way to accomplish this without castings.

Comment: Then change the newInstance method as above

Comment: But this way you're just removing the `bean` instance I'm passing to the factory and instantiating a new one. I could perhaps use a copy constructor like `new BeanOne(bean)`. What still bugs me is the warning `AbstractClass is a raw type. References to generic type AbstractClass<T> should be parameterized`, which can be solved by adding this `AbstractClass<?>`. Still, is this the correct approach or just some hacks to get this working even though it should be done in another way?